# JQuery Accordion does not sort

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an accordion with sub-accordions. When the user hits the "New Topic" button it will create a new accordion by cloning the first accordion in the list. However, when this happens the sub-accordions are not sortable for the additional accordions that were added, but the first two initial accordion's sub-accordions are sortable.

When you try to sort them you can see the accordion dragging but the position does not update, it just goes back to the original position.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?? Below is the JQuery code that I have written so far as well as a demo link.

Thanks

```
var counter = 1;
var subCounter = 1;
var deleteSubcounter = 1;
var deleteCounter = 1;
var subFormCounter = 1;

$(function() {
    indexFunction();
    $('.accordion h3').click(function() {
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            var buttons = $(".remove")
            $(this).find(buttons).hide();
        } else {
            $(".remove").show();
        }
    });
    $('.Subgroup h3').click(function() {
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            var buttons1 = $(".removeSub")
            $(this).find(buttons1).hide();
        } else {
            $(".removeSub").show();
        }
    });
    $("#num").click(function() {

        var aName = "accordion" + (counter + 1);
        var tName = "subtopic" + (counter + 1);
        var tInfo = "subtopicText" + (counter + 1);
        var headerText = "Topic " + (counter + 1);
        var buttonName = "submitInfo" + (counter + 1);
        var divID = "abc" + (counter + 1);
        var formID = "form" + (counter + 1);
        var formTextName = subFormCounter + "subtopicText" + subCounter;
        var subtopicName = subFormCounter + "subtopic" + subCounter;
        var subPosition = subFormCounter + "position" + subCounter;
        var subButtonName = subFormCounter + "submitButton" + subCounter;
        var divSubName = (subFormCounter + 1) + "subAccordion" + subCounter;
        counter++;
        subFormCounter++;
        indexFunction();
        $(".group1:first").clone(true).appendTo("#main");
        $(".group1:last").attr("name", aName);
        $(".remove:last").css("visibility", "visible");
        //$(".group1:last").attr("id", divID);



        if (counter == 10) {
            $("#num").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else if (counter < 10) {
            $("#num").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        indexFunction();


    });
    $(".remove").click(function() {

        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        counter--;
        if (counter < 10) {
            $("#num").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        indexFunction();

    });
    $(".removeSub").click(function() {

        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        subCounter--;

    });
    $("div.accordion")
        .accordion({
            header: "> div > h3",
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content",
            active: false
        })
        .sortable({
            axis: "y",
            handle: "h3",
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
                indexFunction();
                // Refresh accordion to handle new order
                $("this").accordion("refresh");
            }
        });
     $(".newSub1").click(function() {

        if($('.accordion').hasClass('ui-accordion-content-active')) 
        {

        var test = $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
        var active = $(".accordion #sub").eq(test)
        var subName = "subAccordion" + (subCounter + 1);
        var formName = "form" + (subCounter + 1);
        var formTextName = subFormCounter + "subtopicText" + (subCounter + 1);
        var subtopicName = subFormCounter + "subtopic" + (subCounter + 1);
        var subPosition = subFormCounter + "position" + (subCounter + 1);
        var subButtonName = subFormCounter + "submitButton" + (subCounter + 1);
        var divSubName = subFormCounter + "subAccordion" + (subCounter + 1);
        var divID = "abc" + (counter + 1);
        subCounter++;
        $(".Subgroup:first").clone(true).appendTo(active);
        $(".info1:last").children(".formText1").val("");
        $(".info1:last").children(".formText2").val("");
        $(".info1:last").children(".formText3").val("");
        $(".removeSub:last").css("visibility", "visible");
        //var testIndex = $( ".Subgroup" ).index();
        //$(".formText3").val(testIndex);            
        //$(".group1:last").attr("id", divID);

        }
        /*if (subCounter == 10) {
            $(".newSub1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else if (counter < 10) {
            $(".newSub1").removeAttr("disabled");
        }*/




     });

});

var indexFunction = function() {

    var test1 = ($('div#abc1').index() + 1);
    var test2 = ($('div#abc2').index() + deleteCounter);
    var test3 = ($('div#abc3').index() + deleteCounter);
    var test4 = ($('div#abc4').index() + deleteCounter);
    var test5 = ($('div#abc5').index() + deleteCounter);
    var test6 = ($('div#abc6').index() + deleteCounter);
    var test7 = ($('div#abc7').index() + deleteCounter);
    var test8 = ($('div#abc8').index() + deleteCounter);
    var test9 = ($('div#abc9').index() + deleteCounter);
    var test10 = ($('div#abc10').index() + deleteCounter);

    $("#form1").children(".formText3").val(test1);
    $("#form2").children(".formText3").val(test2);
    $("#form3").children(".formText3").val(test3);
    $("#form4").children(".formText3").val(test4);
    $("#form5").children(".formText3").val(test5);
    $("#form6").children(".formText3").val(test6);
    $("#form7").children(".formText3").val(test7);
    $("#form8").children(".formText3").val(test8);
    $("#form9").children(".formText3").val(test9);
    $("#form10").children(".formText3").val(test10);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3L7y5jj/4/

Comment: Your fiddle works for me in Chrome

Comment: You were able to create a new topic and were able to sort the sub accordions for that new topic?

Comment: Yes, The clone worked as expected. Where any text in the first box was cloned in the new accordion. Dragging a newly created accordion to 1st position was used to clone new as expected. I was able to drag the new accordion to an available spot. Able to delete and recreate.  Using Version 46.0.2490.80 m

Comment: Okay this is strange. I just tried my fiddle on a different computer, using Chrome and it does not work. I create a new accordion, open that new accordion and try to sort the accordions that are within the new one and you can drag them but when you release, the selected accordion snaps back to its original position.

Comment: I just retried and it still works for me. :(

Comment: Topic & subtopic creation and sorts

Comment: Sorry to keep pushing the issue but I have been stuck with this problem for weeks now. I made a video capture of what is happening to me.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9vqDVR4xwHHd3pmWW15NENCdTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Followed your video precisely. I am able to duplicate your issue.

Comment: Working in  the fiddle ...

Comment: okay I have no idea what's happening on my end then. This is frustrating haha

Comment: I mean I am trying to make it work in the fiddle. sry

Comment: Based on the .clone() I think it should work but it does not. I tried re-accordion-ing the Subgroup and that failed too. I am out of break time now. If this is not resolved I will look at it again tomorrow. sry.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, much appreciated!! I noticed that if you add   

' items: ".Subgroup",  '

to the .sortable() then the sub-accordions all become sortable, but then the main accordions are no longer sortable. Not sure if that helps you out any.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not calling `.sortable` on the new accordians when you create them.

Comment: How would I go about making sure that .sortable gets called for the new accordions?